# How to import an external module with rollup and karma

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, rollupjs

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/wooorm/markdown-table) library to generate some console output from my application. I'm running my tests using karma with jasmine framework and preprocessing my source and test files with buble compiler and rollup bundler. I have tested that the whole setup is working as expected and all my tests return success.

However, when I try to import the external library in one of my application's files, I get one of the following errors depending on how I try to manage the import:

```
var table = require('../node_modules/markdown-table/index.js')
```

Can't find variable: require

```
import {markdownTable} from '../node_modules/markdown-table/index.js'
```

'markdownTable' is not exported by node_modules/markdown-table/index.js

```
import * as markdownTable from '../node_modules/markdown-table/index.js'
```

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module

Looking at the library source code, there's this line in the [index.js](https://github.com/wooorm/markdown-table/blob/master/index.js), so supposedly the import name should be correct. There's no default import defined.

```
module.exports = markdownTable;
```

The project I'm working on is a standalone npm package using the es6 syntax with no frameworks. I don't have a lot of experience working with modern js and I would like to know how to get an external npm package imported correctly. Rollup has the global and path properties in the configuration but I'm not quite sure what those are for and couldn't fix my problem with tweaking those options.

Comment: Have you tried `import markdownTable from`? That would normally be the expected form.

Comment: When I try to use the default import like you suggest I get the following error: `'default' is not exported by node_modules/markdown-table/index.js`

Comment: While not an ideal solution, I have this currently working after removing the `module.exports = markdownTable;` and adding `export default` to the markdownTable function in the library. For some reason, the module.exports is causing a hickup with my compiler/bundler setup: `cant find variable: module` like I mentioned above.